Power Ink Flushing for Epson EcoTank inkjet printer, possible on Ubuntu?
It's a USB-connected Epson Inkjet printer, and it got clogged for not using it for just one week. I tried regular nozzle cleaning two times, but it did not fix the clogging. I ran the Power Ink Flushing and it solved the problem. But this feature seems only available on Windows. Is this also possible on Ubuntu, or do I have to use Windows for this feature?
https://www.stechies.com/power-flush-clean-your-head-epson-l805/

you may be able to use CUPS to achieve this task. If its installed you can run it from http://localhost:631/admin or if it has an IP address assigned, from your browser directly. This Canonical resource explains more.
